# How to fix timestamp in character class to correct format in R?

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct, strptime

I am having trouble converting timestamps in character class. I am trying to use following function

```
df$Time <- strptime(df$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

Then problem I have is that my Time column (currently class Character) has values listed like this 1:00:05 or 55:42. There are no dates in the column.

While the 55:45 is in mm:ss, the 1:00:05 is in hh:mm:ss. Could this be the problem? I can't think of anything else. When I run the above function, I keep getting NA for the whole column. How can I resolve this.

Thanks for any help. I have been stuck and have tried so many different functions such as hms from lubridate and as.POSIXct

Here is sample dataset

```
df <- data.frame(Time = c("1:00:05", "55:45","34:33","1:12:35"))
df$Time <- as.character(df$Time)
head(df)
```

Comment: Can you try with `parse_date_time` ? `library(lubridate);parse_date_time(df$Time, c("HMS", "MS"))`

Comment: *"trouble converting timestamps in character class"*: please clarify: they are already `character` class, do you want to convert them to `POSIXt` or just `numeric`? The former doesn't know the date, so it would have to default so some day (e.g., today).

Comment: My column is already in character class and I am trying to convert it to POSIXt

Comment: @Sanam The `parse_date_time` should have worked for you if it is already character

Comment: Okay, so what date? R `POSIXt` object in R means date/time, not just time. If this is not attached to a particular date, then either (a) you use today always (perhaps problematic depending on the context), or (b) you use `lubridate::hms` to return a different class. How are you intending to use the result?

Comment: akrun's suggestion returns `"0000-01-01 01:00:05 UTC" "0000-01-01 00:55:45 UTC" ...`, if that doesn't work then please explain why that isn't sufficient.

Comment: @akrun The parse_date_time worked! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

We may use `parse_date_time`

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(df$Time, c("HMS", "MS"))
```